# How to use Observable.fromPromise in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

My code is like following:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Observable.fromPromise(promise).mergeMap(value => {
   // some code
});
```

But it doesn't work in Angular 8. How to do sometimes like above in Angular 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 8 uses RxJS Version 6.5 or greater.

`fromPromise` is no longer a part of the `RxJS`.

You should use [**`from`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html) instead.

Here's how:

```
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

//emit 'Hello'
const source = from(new Promise(resolve => resolve('Hello')));
//map to inner observable and flatten
const example = source.pipe(mergeMap(val => of(`${val} World!`)));
//output: 'Hello World!'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3wbeca?file=index.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use mergeMap with from? Could you give an example?